# Why we used vector format for bitmaps for different android dpi?

Tags: android

on android developer site:
you should start with your raw resource in vector format and generate the images for each density using the following size scale:

xhdpi: 2.0
hdpi: 1.5
mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
ldpi: 0.75

Answer (score 0):

You should do that for different screen densities to support all devices. If you didn't do that, and put for example a large image in your drawable folder, that image might be displayed well on high density screens but not well on low density screens (It will be so large in your layout causing issues for your layout). I recommend you to also read this doc for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html